# Linux development server

Tags: linux, webserver, development

I have an issue. I want to set up a Linux development server on my home PC so everyone who has credentials can log in from anywhere into that machine and write code. What should I do or what should I read to achieve this?  So already I have installed X Ubuntu on my PC and that's all.

Comment: Hi and wecome to Unix & Linux. Your question is too broad. Try breaking it up into smaller tasks and if you get stuck with those, then ask for each of them independently. Since you're just starting out I'd take a look for tutorials vs. asking questions on this site like the one above. Also look at howtoforge for tutorials such as this one: http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-a-home-media-and-file-server-with-ubuntu

Comment: Also try searching within this site, your question has been asked in a variety of ways before and is typically closed due to it's broad nature, the stackexchange sites are for targeted Q&A's on very specific topics. However there are still may Q+A's on this site that will help you on your journey: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=getting+started+with+linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site! I'll give it a quick shot, since we've all been there before.

> If your goal is allowing others to connect to your server...

1. OS: Install your operating system.
2. Network: Make sure you're connected to the network.
3. SSH-Server: Make sure you have your SSH server installed so others can connect to you.
4. Users: Learn how to add/delete users.

A little detail on each of those.

1. OS: You're using Ubuntu. A good choice, based on Debian.
2. Network: Ubuntu uses DHCP to assign you an IP address. If you want to set a static IP address (so it doesn't change), search for "ubuntu static IP address."
3. SSH-Server: During an Ubuntu install you should select "SSH server" from the optional install packages. If you missed this and don't want to start over, do `apt-get update`, then `apt-get install openssh-server`.
4. Users: Very easy. On Ubuntu do `man adduser` and `man deluser`.